# Count items inside the action bar icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I creating a ecommerce app, how to count items inside my cart icon? and display it with Badge. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us your code. Where is the exact problem? What did you try to do? What do you mean with cart icon?

Answer (score 1):

Create a saprate layout for cart icon and count ex.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/save"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sir what todo next ? how it will count the items inside my cart?

Comment: Count your cart items length , its totaly your choise